# Discord.js dev version Modal

Tags: discord.js

If I remember correctly, the dev version of discord.js had introduced modals, I tried to import Modal from discord.js, I'm not sure if it was supposed to be imported from other package or if it really isn't implemented yet in dev version but I get **Modal is not a constructor**.

I imported it as

```
const { Modal } = require("discord.js")
```

And the version I installed of discord.js is

```
^14.0.0-dev.1645402068.78aa36f
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your request and provide code snippets.

Comment: I was able to solve it, I don't think the dev version had Modals yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [pull request](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/7023) (#7023) is open, and will soon be merged, but it's not published yet.

If you want to use modals right now, you can use that branch, or you could wait until the PR is merged.